# Get default YouTube channel in YouTube API

Tags: android, api, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I have a problem with Youtube API that I can't solve. I would need to select a YouTube channel from my Google account to get the name and id channel. My Google account has two channels (channel1 [**default**], channel2). At the moment there aren't an Android native method to do that ([link](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api.html)):

> if you are an Android developer who is using OAuth 2 (there is
>   currently no native Android account switcher)

*note: YouTube App has an account switcher*

In this scenario I tried to follow this:

> Use the Advanced Account Settings tool to select which channel should
>   be used. This is recommended when a user has one channel they want to
>   use for all applications.

Done. Now the default channel is channel2. And then I did:

> If you’re still using version 2 of the YouTube Data API, you can
>   retrieve the profile of the special identifier default

Result: the response of http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default still send channel1 like default (channel2 isn't appear on the response).

I would need to get the default channel information (name, id, etc..).